# How to add react pagination in reactjs with server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React app that uses redux for state management and react-redux-dom for routing. Here I am trying to add react pagination. Although I have added the react pagination by looking at some online resource I got into some problem.

Initially when the page loads it shows URL `/notice` but when I click on pagination `1` it goes to another page but it doesn't show '1' to go back to page one.

Here is my code

> app.js

```
 <PrivateRoute exact path="/notice" component={NoticeMobile} />
```

> NoticeMobile.jsx

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handlePageChange();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    this.handlePageChange();
  }

  handlePageChange = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const page = parseInt(params.get('page'))|| 0;
    if(page !== this.props.notice.number){
        this.props.noticeList(20, page);
    }
  }
```

> pagination component

```
{notice.first !== true ?
<li className={`page-item first-item ${notice.number === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
<Link to={{ search: `?page=1` }} className="page-link">1</Link>
                              </li>: ''
                          }                          

{pageNumbers.map(page =><li key={page} className={`page-item number-item ${notice.number === page ? 'active' : ''}`}>
<Link to={{ search: `?page=${page}` }} className="page-link">{page}</Link>
                              </li>

                          )}
{notice.last !== true ? <li className={`page-item last-item ${notice.number === notice.totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
<Link to={{ search: `?page=${notice.totalPages}` }} className="page-link">{'>'}</Link></li>: ''
                          }
```

> This is how my data looks like
>   [image: data]
>   I m not sure if it right or not.

Comment: Could you please add a codepen?

Comment: @GalAbra i followed this tutorial https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/07/18/react-node-server-side-pagination-tutorial-example

Comment: Note that the link to the first page will only appear once `notice.first` is false - I think this is where you should look